# SSRS How to format a line line chart depending if the line goes up or down?

Tags: ssrs-2012

Does anyone know how to format a line chart depending if the line goes up or down (from left to right), I need the line to display green color every time the line goes up, and red if it decreases.

thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry to let you down, but as logical as your requirement is, I believe it is not possible to add conditional formatting of the color on a single line in SSRS. You can refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156400(v=sql.100).aspx) and see the logic behind the conditional formatting at the reporting services.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I will keep looking.